# I'm having some trouble with C++11 in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, osx-lion

I'm a Mac OS X Lion user who uses Xcode for C++, and it appears that no updates are available for Xcode.  I do not appear to be able to compile C++11-exclusive code, but for whatever reason, I thought Apple had gotten C++11 pretty much implemented.  And yes, I do have support for Command Line Tools.

Then again, that might just be me.  If so, is there any sort of IDE that supports C++11, or any way to upgrade?

Comment: Xcode 4.2 ships with clang and clang supports C++11 partially. You can switch to clang in the build options.

Comment: You can use Macports, they ship all the newest gcc versions http://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use Xcode and set the following settings:

**C++ language dialect**: C++11 or GNU++11

**C++ Standart Library**: libc++ (LLVM C++ standart library with C++11 support)

Xcode version: 4.3.2

[image: XCode project settings]

Comment: Don't forget to select the LLVM compiler also.

Comment: I have problem with linking std lib. If I choose libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support) then linker cannot link "std::string::find(char, unsigned long) const" and other symbols, if i choose libstc++ (GNU C++ Standart library) then there are compiler errors in headers "cannot find ::std::move" . What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: We also need to modify the file name from .m to .mm

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Xcode 4.3 there are several relevant project settings you need to use C++11 features.  The first is to use the clang compiler.  Something like

```
GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
```

in your `.xcconfig` will set it, or you can use the GUI.

Next, you need to tell LLVM which C++ standard to use:

```
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu++11
```

This will make language features like range based for, delegated constructors, etc. available.

Finally, if you want to use C++11 STL features (such as `std::unordered_map`) you need to use the libc++ STL:

```
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm very new, but how exactly do I do that?  Apparently, those are commands for LLVM or something of the sort, but I really don't know what to do.

Comment: If you're not using .xcconfig files you can select your project file in Xcode's inspector and you should see a list of options similar to what Alexander posted.

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 5 / opencv 2.4.9, I can select:

[image: XCode settings]

And it builds without error.
If i set the libc++ without specifying C++ Language Dialect then I get same issue as OP