# Alternative to std::default_random_engine for Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, random, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a program I wrote in linux on Xcode and for my random functions I used:

```
std::random_device seed_device;
std::default_random_engine engine(seed_device());
```

But default_random_engine won't compile on Xcode. Is there a different version I should use?

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting from the compiler? Chances are that when `default_random_engine` doesn't work the others won't work quite well either without some fix.

Comment: I have no problem using `std::random_device` with apple's clang version (more precisely Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), which should be the compiler installed with xcode 6.2). However, that's a C++11 feature, are you sure you chose the C++11 dialect (Edit: and a standard library with C++11 support)? (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438253/im-having-some-trouble-with-c11-in-xcode) for instance)

Comment: The errors I'm getting are "no type named 'random_device' in namespace 'std'" and "no member named 'default_random_engine' in namespace 'std'". How I double check that Xcode is using C++11? I just updated everything and assumed it was.

Comment: Are you including `<random>`?

Comment: Crap, that was it, thanks. Why doesn't g++ in linux need to include it for it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <random>`.

In general, when the compiler complains about "*no type named `function_name` in namespace `std`*", you have to check that:

- You have included the right header. You can look up the name of the right header on any decent C++ reference.
- Your standard library supports C++1x (*) (or, at least, the feature you want).
- Your compiler supports C++1x (*) (or, at least, the feature you want), and the right flags are used to enable it, if required.

(*) The x stands for the version of the C++ standard that includes the feature you want.